# Play: Unit test for controller class method w/ injections

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to write tests for methods of a controller class that contains injected dependencies

This is my test class implementation:

```
public class MyTestClass {
   private static Application app;

   @BeforeClass
   public static void beforeTest() {
      app = Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase());
      Helpers.start(app);

      // .....
   }

   @AfterClass
   public static void afterTest() {
       Helpers.stop(app);
   }

   @Test
   public void testSomething() {

       // .....
       app.injector().instanceOf(MyController.class).processSomething();

       // Some assertions here..
   }

}
```

---

`MyController.processSomething()` method contains some implementation that involves the usage of an injected FormFactory object.

And when I try to run, I'll get a `null` value

```
[error] Test MyTestClass.testSomething failed: null, took 0.137 sec
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         MyTestClass
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
```

Question: How do I make sure the controller I'm testing is able to get its injections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to derive the test class from the WithApplication instead of handling manually the application life-cycle. This will look something like this

```
public class MyTestClass extends WithApplication {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        Helpers.running(Helpers.fakeApplication(), () -> {
            // *whatever mocking*
            RequestBuilder mockActionRequest = Helpers.fakeRequest(
                                         controllers.routes.MyController.processSomething());
            Result result = Helpers.route(mockActionRequest);
            // *whatever assertions* 
       });
     }
}
```

You can fine [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/06/unit-testing-powermock-mocking-play.html) more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, play.api.test.Helpers is really helpful. If you use Parameterized Tests and don't want a full start/shutdown in between use something like this `@BeforeClass`:
`
import play.api.test.Helpers
object Tests {
  var app: Application = _

  @BeforeClass
  def setUpApp() {
    Tests.app = Helpers.baseApplicationBuilder.build()
  }
}
`